# Python: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

I am with an App written in Python 3.6.8 (for Android) that returns this error from mobiles when accessing from urllib.request (Python3) to a JSON file of a URL hosted on a web page.

This is the error:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c: 1051)
```

Running the script from the desktop on windows (W7) and in linux (ubuntu) I don't have this error and I access it perfectly. I have looked for possible solutions online but for now nothing. Does anyone know how to fix it?

I do not understand why I can run the script on Windows and Linux and not on a mobile (Android). Do I need to add some code to the script? Thanks

```
main.py

import socket
import ssl
import urllib.request # Para Python3
import urllib.error
from urllib.request import urlopen

class Api(Screen):
    data_json = StringProperty("")
    def data_api(self):
        try:
            url = "https://...../data.json"
            request_json = urllib.request.Request(
                url, 
                data=None, 
                headers={
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
                }
            )

            context = ssl.SSLContext()
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(request_json, context=context)

            if response.getcode() == 401:
                print("Acces:", str(response.getcode()))

            if response.getcode() == 403:
                print("Acces:", str(response.getcode()))

            if response.getcode() == 200:
                print("Access:", str(response.getcode()))
                data = json.loads(response.read())
                self.data_json = str(data)
                print(data)

        except (urllib.error.HTTPError) as e:
            print("Error: ", e)
```

Comment: *`https://...../data.json`* is not very helpful in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: I don't think the url is the problem, If I replace for this one => url = "https://reqres.in/api/users" , I have the same problem. It could be due to the server requieres some SSL specific code or maybe I need to write more code but in which direction?

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Comment: I haven't solved yet the problem. I suppose I don't have SSL on the local mobile implemented with OpenSSL but I have to make some tests with the hosting SSL and the openSSL. Anway ... any help will be welcomed